# What method does Pinterest use for Facebook login? Registration plugin?

Tags: facebook

If you go to login on Pinterest, 2 big buttons appear, one for Facebook, one for Twitter. I am confused about how the Facebook one works, compared to the Facebook Registration Plugin I have been trying.

On Pinterest, if you click the link you are logged into Facebook, it takes you right to your Pinterest account. When I set up the Facebook Registration Plugin on my own site, it says you are supposed to use an iframe, which loads a form for the user to fill out with whatever info you want from them. I am confused as to how I would just get the user to bypass this iframe on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinterest uses server side OAuth to authenticate using Facebook.

Here's the documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/